# How do I pass down props to another function using TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-props

I am not proficient with TypeScript but I am trying to pass down the {product.picture} which is a string to the function saveInfo() once the user clicked save. I can display the picture but I could not post it to the server once I clicked the save button. The error stated "Cannot find product".

Appreciate any help on this.

```js
function App() {
    
    const saveInfo = async (product) => {
    let response = await axios.post('https://localhost:3000', {
      data: {
        image: `https://image/${product.picture}.png`,
      },
    });

  return (
    <div className="App">
            <div>
                products.map((product: any) => (
                  <div className="product" key={product.id}>
                    <h5>{product.name}</h5>
                    <img
                      src={`https://image/${
                        product.picture as string
                      }.png`}
                      alt="symbol"
                    />
                  </div>
                ))
            </div>
            <button onClick={() => saveInfo(product)}>Save</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your button is outside products map. So this is expected that product is not defined at that place.

Comment: But I do not want buttons on every line. How do I edit in a way that it's within the products map but not in every line?

Comment: Exactly as @CodeThing said.  Also - there is no difference between typescript and javascript in case of sending parameters to the functions, only difference is declaring types in function definition, but thats all really

Comment: How many products do you have? and let's say if the products are greater than 1 then how button will know which product details to send?

Comment: How can the button know which product to save if it's not in every line?

Comment: What if I want to save everything?

Comment: If you want button for some products only then render it conditionally inside map. If you want to save everything then pass whole products to the save function. Your will need to build your expected request in that function